# tiggers orders without explicitly settings?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table which has 3 triggers of update (just for the scenario)...

I didnt explicitly used the `sp_settriggerorder` command to set the order.

What is the order of the Triggers ?

How can I find the Order ,by query ?

p.s.

the `ExecIsFirstUpdateTrigger` doesn't help me here since its working **only** if I use `sp_settriggerorder` to set the order. ( but in my case ive just created 3 update triggers - so how can i get the order ?)

Comment: You can set first trigger and  last trigger so if you have no more than 3 you can ensure the order is deterministic.

Comment: @MartinSmith and if i have 4 tr's I guess its a problem....

Comment: @Royi - Why would you ever want 4 triggers anyway? But yes in that case you can't determine the order of all 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify an order, then there is no inherent order.  This is just like a `SELECT` query - the order that the triggers execute in is the order that SQL Server feels like running them in.

Comment: are you telling me that one day he can execute tr1 first and tomorrow the tr2 trigger first ?

Comment: Typically the execution order will not change randomly like that.  Generally triggers will run in the order in which they were created on the table, but this behavior is not defined in any specification and is certainly not one you should rely on.

Comment: @DaveC what about 5 triggers on a table ? ( first... last - what about 2,3,4 ??)

Comment: Generally, 2, 3, and 4 will execute in the order they were created. However, this is only based on my past experience, is not documented, and could change at any time. Generally speaking, you cannot and should not rely on the order of execution of triggers.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Triggers are like the row order.  If you don't specify an order it will usually be in the same order, but there are no guarantees.